# react native: display props information that coming from another page

Tags: reactjs, json, react-native, react-props, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to print `EquipmentID` inside the flatlist
And for some reason it does not show me its information.
I would like to understand what is wrong with my code.
The data (props) come from another screen .
in my example i show the flatlist screen and the props as it print.

```
const EquipmentContentCardOptions = props => {

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {

    return <Text>{props.EquipmentID}</Text>;
   
  };

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={props}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      keyExtractor={item => item.EquipmentID}
    />
  );
};

export default EquipmentContentCardOptions;
```

this is the props :

```
{
   "EquipSetData":[
      {
         "EquipmentID":"567",
         "EquipmentName":"aaa",
         
      },
      {
         "EquipmentID":"123",
         "EquipmentName":"rrr",
      }
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are passing props directly to the FlatList and then trying to access the EquipSetData's data so what you need to do is

```
 <FlatList
  data={props.EquipSetData}
  renderItem={renderItem}
  keyExtractor={item => item.EquipmentID}
/>
```

Hope this would resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you `console.log(props)` as well as `console.log(item)` to see if they aren't null. If `renderItem` is meant to be a component, then, you have defined it inside another component which is wrong.

Plus the name must start with a capital letter (if it is meant to be a component). You probably need to include the `FlatList` component to see how the props are passed to it.

Comment: i print already the props and i see the data. but if i try to print the item so i dont see it